# hide primary menus only on home page drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal, menu, drupal-6

I want to hide primary menus in home page, Now my site displaying the primary menus in all pages, but my requirement is to display in all pages, execpt in home page.
please help me on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you: [Menu Display](http://views-help.doc.logrus.com/help/views/menu)

Comment: Thanks for your reply., is it possible to hide those menus only on  home page while giving condition in page.tpl.php... please help meto resolve this issue ..

Comment: Yes .. i got solution., use this on page.tpl.php to hide primary menu only on home page 
<?php if (isset($primary_links)  && ! $is_front) : ?>